# How to convert sourceSets from a project to kotlin kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi module gradle project. I'm converting all build.gradle configuration files to Kotlin kts.

But I can't find how to convert this code below to kotlin kts.

I tried to place groovy code inside kts and checked the documentation, but I could't find anything.

```
    testCompile project(":entities").sourceSets.test.output
```

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I found that the syntax in this area has changed recently.

- This gives some history:
  https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/577
- The Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC3 introduced some breaking changes:
  https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/releases/tag/v1.0-RC3
- the sourceSets collection does still exist on the project:   https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:sourceSets)
- this collection can be cross-referenced via a peer project

I tried a few variants, and discovered that:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation(project(":entities").sourceSets["test"].output)
}
```

results in

```
testImplementation(project(":entities").sourceSets["test"].output)
                                     ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                                                        public val Project.sourceSets: SourceSetContainer defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

But the following works just fine, as long as the Java plugin is enabled:

```
val entityTests: SourceSetOutput = project(":entities").sourceSets["test"].output

dependencies {
  testImplementation(entityTests)
}
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work, I still get `Unresolved reference: sourceSets`. But when I add `java` before `sourceSets`, it works, however, I get build error which didn't happen before.

Comment: The sourceSets property of a project is only activated when the Java plugin is enabled. See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N159F7. I'll update my answer to include this. I might be able to help with the build error if you provide some further information.

Comment: Only works if the val is not declared in dependencies block (just FYI)

Answer (score 1):

This also works for me.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(project(":entities").dependencyProject.sourceSets["test"].output)
}
```